# Python: How to increase the dimensions of a matrix without expanding it?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, concatenation

I am quite new in Python, and am currently working on a code in which I want to store previous iterations of an 3-dimensional matrix, a version of which is created in each single step of a for-loop. The way I want to go about this is by concatenating a new array of dimension 3+1=4, which stores the previous values. Now this is possible with concatenation, and I got it to work like this:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.ones((1,lay,row,col), dtype=np.float32)

for n in range(100):
    if n == 0:
        # initialize the storage matrix
        matrix_stored = matrix
    else:
        # append further matrices in first dimension
        matrix_stored = np.concatenate((matrix_stored,matrix),axis = 0)
```

so here's my question: the code above requires that the matrix already is in four-dimensional structure [1 x m x n x o]. For my purposes, however, I would prefer to keep the variable matrix three-dimensional [m x n x o], and only transform it into a four-dimensional form when feeding it into the variable matrix_stored.

Is there a way to facilitate such a conversion?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). In particular, at the point of passing your matrix to the function, you'll reshape it like this:

```
your_function(matrix.reshape(1, *matrix.shape))
```

Where `matrix.shape` prints out the existing dimensions of your matrix.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: a shorthand way to add a dimension with length 1 is to index with `None`

```
np.concatenate((matrix_stored,matrix[None]),axis = 0)
```

But most of all I like to warn  you against concatenating arrays in a loop. Compare these timings:

```
In [31]: %%timeit
    ...: a = np.ones((1,1000))
    ...: A = a.copy()
    ...: for i in range(1000):
    ...:     A = np.concatenate((A, a))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.76 s per loop

In [32]: %timeit a = np.ones((1000,1000))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.02 ms per loop
```

This happens because `concatenate` copies the data from the source arrays into an entirely new array. And each iteration of the loop more and more data needs to be copied.

It's better to allocate in advance:

```
In [33]: %%timeit
    ...: A = np.empty((1000, 1000))
    ...: a = np.ones((1,1000))
    ...: for i in range(1000):
    ...:     A[i] = a
100 loops, best of 3: 3.42 ms per loop
```